# Prime decomposition in $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^3-x^2+x+1)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> If $K$ is the unique number field of discriminant $-44$, K is isomorphic
>   to the field generated over $\mathbb Q$ by a root of the polynomial $x^3-x^2+x+1$ with $\mathcal O_K=\mathbb Z[x]/(x^3-x^2+x+1)$, find the factorization of $2\mathcal O_K$ into a product of prime ideals $\mathfrak p_i$ and determine the inertial degree $f_{\mathfrak p_i}$ the dimension of the $\mathbb F_2$-vector space $\mathcal O/\mathfrak p_i$, that is $f_{p_i}=\dim_{\mathbb F_2}(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p_i)$

now by the equation $[K:\mathbb Q]=3=\sum_i=e_if_i$, we have that $(2)$ has a decomposition into a product of at most $3$ prime ideals, but since $2\mid -44$, $2$ is ramified, this implies that $(2)=\mathfrak p_1^{e_1}\mathfrak p_2^{e_2}$, with $\max \{e_1,e_2\}>1$

If I factorize $x^3-x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb F_2$

$[x^3-x^2+x+1]=[(x^3-x^2)+(x+1)]=[x^2(x-1)+(x-1)]=[(x^2-1)(x-1)]=[(x-1)^3]$

(since in $\mathbb F_2$ negative and positive are considedered to be the same and $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$)

Is then $(2)$ prime in $\mathcal O_K$ now ?

How can I continue ?

Comment: how did a degree 3 polynomial turn into a degree 5 polynomial ?

Comment: @mercio OK I'll edit it

Comment: The calculation of the factorization still has some degree-related issues. (But the result is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In fact, you have computed $\mathcal O_K/2 \cong \mathbb F_2[x]/(x-1)^3$, which implies that $(2) = (2,\alpha-1)^3$ is the prime factorization of $2$, where $\alpha\in\mathcal O_K$ with $\alpha^3-\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$.

Indeed, any prime ideal $\mathfrak p | 2$ gets sent to a prime ideal of $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x-1)^3$ under the above isomorphism, which just corresponds to a factor of $(x-1)^3$. On the other hand, $(x-1)$ has preimage $(2,\alpha-1)$.

It should be easy to figure out the inertia degree from here.